# Horizontal Radio Button 960 Grid - jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, radio-button, radio-group

I am working on a jQuery Mobile Project. I need to create 3 Horizontal radio button that stretched to full width. I`ve worked on the normal grid, but I was unable to stretch the width. So now working with 960 grid. It increases the space between the button instead of stretching the button to full width. Please help me with it.

```
    <div data-role="content"  >
    <p align="center" class="msg"> Apply leave </p>

    <fieldset class="container_12">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  class="row_b"> 


<div class="grid_2"> <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2_0" value="0" checked="checked" data-mini="true" /></div>
            <label for="q2_0">C Leave</label>
        <div class="grid_2">   <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2_1" value="1" data-mini="true" /></div>
            <label for="q2_1">s Leave</label>
           <div class="grid_2"> <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2_2" value="2" data-mini="true" /></div>
            <label for="q2_2">P Leave</label>


    </fieldset> </fieldset> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls
{
    width:100% !important;
}
.ui-radio {
    width:33% !important;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yUZy8/

Comment: I did the same thing but can`t figure out why I am getting like this.. :( http://jsfiddle.net/jCFha/ pls help me if possible..

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/VvZ22/ You should use jQM 1.2 and you had twice called older versions of jQM js and jQM css files. Tell me if everything works now.

Comment: Copied the same code and checked with my browsers.. None of them are supporting this js,.. pls check with this image http://snag.gy/Bp7Df.jpg

Comment: Ashwin could you please send your html file to my mail, I will check what have you done. You can find my email in my profile or my personal web page.

Comment: It`s working superbly when I insert one more CSS file.. Thanks a lot :)